How to add pytest markers to multiple paramterize
I have the below block of code.
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("project_name", [
    pytest.param("default", marks=pytest.mark.defa),
    pytest.param("remote", marks=[pytest.mark.remote, pytest.mark.nightly])
 ])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("spec_file", [
    pytest.param("some_A.json", marks=pytest.mark.nightly),
    pytest.param("some_B.json")
])
def test_A(self, project_name, spec_file):
    assert 1==1

If I try to collect/run the nightly marker using pytest -m nightly --collect-only -qq <path_to_test_file> command I am getting the below output
<Function 'test_A[some_A.json-remote]'>
<Function 'test_A[some_A.json-default]'>
<Function 'test_A[some_B.json-remote]'>

I was expecting it to collect or run only <Function 'test_A[some_A.json-remote]'> params.
I have a questions here:
How do I make pytest understand to run only <Function 'test_A[some_A.json-remote]'> case?

This behaviour happens because the nightly mark applied to both project_name and spec_file params, resulting in multiple combinations.
I could see only 2 possible solutions:

Use single param:

@pytest.mark.parametrize("project_name, spec_file", [
    pytest.param("default","some_A.json", marks=pytest.mark.defa),
    pytest.param("remote","some_A.json", marks=pytest.mark.nightly),
    pytest.param("remote","some_B.json", marks=pytest.mark.remote),
])
def test_A(project_name, spec_file):
    assert 1==1


Use condition inside of test:

@pytest.mark.parametrize("project_name", [
    pytest.param("default", marks=pytest.mark.defa),
    pytest.param("remote", marks=pytest.mark.remote)
])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("spec_file", [
    pytest.param("some_A.json", marks=pytest.mark.nightly),
    pytest.param("some_B.json")
])
def test_A(project_name, spec_file):
    if project_name == "remote" and spec_file == "some_A.json":
        pytest.mark.nightly
    assert 1==1

